# RegisterStartupScript causes window.opener to be null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, window.opener, registerstartupscript

I'm having trouble getting the window.opener value to transfer between child popup windows. This code works in IE 8 and order, but quit working in IE 9 and newer. Any input is appreciated. 

Explained a different way. My sister knows that I'm her brother but doesn't trust me to tell her who our parents are.

**Process Flow:**
Parent window (Main form) -> Opens popup window (PopUp 1)
User clicks button on PopUp 1 to open PopUp 2.
PopUp 2 opens: 
    It pulls data from PopUp 1 then closes PopUp 1
User clicks button(Save) on PopUp 2.
PopUp 2 refreshes the data on the original parent "Main form". Then closes itself. 

The last step is the step that is not happing IE 9. I created the sample below to show the functionality works using pure JavaScript but fails when posting back and using RegisterStartupScript to call the JavaScript function. We are using the RegisterStartupScript because the save action of the form has many different outcomes based on the user's input.

All pages are in the same domain.


**MainForm.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MainForm.aspx.vb" Inherits="MainForm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenPopUp() {
            document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerHTML = '';
            window.open('PopUp1.aspx', '',
                 'width=750,left=' + ((screen.width / 2) - 375) + ',top=' + ((screen.height / 2) - 250) +
                 ',height=500,location=no,menubar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,resizable=yes');
        }

        function Refresh() {
            document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerHTML = 'It Worked';
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open Popup" style="width: 110px" onclick="OpenPopUp()" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PopUp1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="PopUp1.aspx.vb" Inherits="PopUp1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OpenPopUp2() {
                window.open('PopUp2.aspx', '', 'width=700,left=' + ((screen.width / 2) - 350) + ',top=' +
                ((screen.height / 2) - 275) + ',height=550,location=no,status=yes,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes');
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is pop up 1</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPop1" runat="server" Text="test 1" ></asp:TextBox>
        <input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open Popup 2" style="width: 110px" onclick="OpenPopUp2()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PopUp2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="PopUp2.aspx.vb" Inherits="PopUp2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GrabData() {      
        var oParentDoc = window.opener.document;
        if (oParentDoc != null) {
            try { document.getElementById('txtPop2').value = oParentDoc.getElementById('txtPop1').value; } catch (ex1) { }
        }     
        var oParentOpener = window.opener.opener;
        window.opener.close();
        window.opener = oParentOpener;
    }

    function MyClose() {
        window.opener.Refresh();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is pop up 2</h1>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPop2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button" id="btnSave1" value="Save Working" style="width: 110px" onclick="MyClose()" />       
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Not Working" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PopUp2.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class PopUp2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "Refresh", _
                    "<script type=""text/javascript"">GrabData();</script>")
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "RestoreFilter", _
            "<script type=""text/javascript"">MyClose();</script>", False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.form1.GetType(), "RestoreFilter", _
        "<script type=""text/javascript"">MyClose();</script>", False)
End Sub
```

Be (see the GetType part):

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "RestoreFilter", _
        "<script type=""text/javascript"">MyClose();</script>", False)
End Sub
```